# Django create a view to generate a receipt

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I want to create a small app that creates a kind off  receipt record in to a db table, from two other tables. very much like a receipt from a grocery store  where a cashier makes a sell and the ticket contains multiple items,  calculates a total and subtotal  and return values to the database. I currently have 3 tables: the Ticket table where i would like to insert the values of all calculations and ticket info, the services table that acts like an inventory of services available. this has the service name and price for each service and  my responsible table that has a list of "cashiers" or people that will make the sale and their percentage for their commissions, i have the views to create , edit and delete cashier's and  services.

What I don't have is a way to create the ticket. I am completely lost.  can you guys point me in to the correct path on what to look for.  i am learning to program son i don't have a lot  of knowledge in this if its even possible. i don't need the system to print i just want to have all record stored this way later on i can expand on it and create reports of sold items and who sold them and how much commissions each seller has won.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create relationships to two other models (tables) from the Ticket model (table). Luckily you don't have to create the relations in the database tables itself. Use django model's Foreign key fields to accomplish this. Here is the documentation link:

[Django Models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/)

You may need to read it several times to get the concepts thoroughly.

Comment: I already have! What I have    on my Ticket class  is a field call 
cashier =models.ForeignKey(Responsible) and items = models.ManyToManyField(Services)

Comment: Then have you created forms to get data from the user? After user submits data you can do validations and create an object of the model.

Comment: I have created the forms to populate and edit two of my tables .. the thing that I'm missing is the view for the actual ticket creation

Comment: Is the view you referring here is the function that get called when the URL pattern is matched with the request? Or there are class based views (hard for beginners) to avoid code duplication and rework when needed. Use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial03/